# Save and send cookies in Angular Ajax requests to backend in different domain

Tags: angularjs, ajax, node.js, express, session-cookies

Guys I'm having a very difficult problem here:

I have this Angular SPA running at port 3000, and a NodeJS Express app running on port 8080.

The SPA sends an Ajax HTTP request to the Express app and the Express creates a session for it. The Express app will write a Headers Parameter in the response for the SPA to create a cookie with the session ID (I don't control this behavior, this is how sessions work) for further requests. This parameter is the Set-Cookie.

The problem is that the SPA doesn't receive nor create the cookie. So it will never send cookies in the future.

Does anybody have a solution or a workaround for this? I spent hours trying to have an insight or read an actual answer for this, but with no success.

Comment: you need `withCredentials` set for cookies to be passed cross domain. See `$http` docs

Comment: hey, I tested it earlier with `$httpProvider` and now again with `$http`. Everytime I use withCredentials, I can't send the post due to CORS, I guess. I just added it to the code and I had the same problem.

Comment: You are right, i had to make some changes in backend though